# mysql_upgrade and MySQL service - Vicious Circle

Tags: mysql, mysqlupgrade

I am upgrading MySQL server 5.067 to 5.5.60 on Windows 10.

I stopped the service, replaced bin a shared directory and started the service.

Service start failed with the message (in Event Viewer):

```
Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://www.mysql.com.
```

OK, so I opened cmd as admin with the command:

```
mysql_upgrade --port 64202
```

With result:

```
Looking for 'mysql.exe' as: C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\MySQLServer\bin\mysql.exe
Looking for 'mysqlcheck.exe' as: C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\MySQLServer\bin\mysqlcheck.exe
Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

The design of MySQL upgrade is connecting over TCP to MySQL to run the upgrade, but how it can possibly work if the service is not running? It is a vicious circle - MySQL service needs to be upgraded to be able to start and mysql_upgrade needs to connect to running service.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Skipping major versions (5.1) is not supported, and may or may not work.  The appropriate upgrade is one of:

Plan A:  Upgrade to 5.1, then to 5.5.  Run `mysql_upgrade` *at each step*.

Plan B:  Dump the data from 5.0 with mysqldump.  (Be sure to get routines, etc).  Blow away (or bypass) 5.0 and install a fresh 5.5.  Load the data back in.  There *may* be syntax errors in the dump file, edit the file if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're upgrading from 5.0 to 5.5, there are configuration values which are deprecated, causing the engine to be unable to start.

Most likely culprit is `skip-dbd`, as explained on [this site](https://ma.ttias.be/mysql-table-mysql-plugin-doesnt-exist-after-mysql-upgrade/).

So: find your MySQL configuration file, comment out the `skip-dbd` option and restart the MySQL service. Then you can run `mysql_upgrade` with the appropriate options including authentication.